# Move files from one folder to another from a list of filenames from a text file

Tags: powershell, cmd, windows-7, command-prompt

I have a text file which contains a list of file names with extension(no spaces in the filename). 
[image]

I have two folders in two different paths, say, C:\ThirdParty and C:\Users. There will be subfolders in these paths.

### What I need?

I need to search each filename in the text file on these two folders and its subfolders and **move** the exact matching files to another folders say, C:\Backup\ThirdParty and C:\Backup\Users.

How can i do this in Windows 7 with powershell or command prompt.

I have no idea how to start or I am zero at powershell and DOS commands.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This script can be used for `C:\ThirdParty` and adapted for you needs.

```
$file_list = Get-Content C:\list.txt
$search_folder = "C:\ThirdParty"
$destination_folder = "C:\Backup\ThirdParty"

foreach ($file in $file_list) {
    $file_to_move = Get-ChildItem -Path $search_folder -Filter $file -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force | % { $_.FullName}
    if ($file_to_move) {
        Move-Item $file_to_move $destination_folder
    }
}
```

With `Get-Content` you retrieve the list of your files (one per line) in an array called `$file_list`.

You set a `$search_folder` and then a loop for each file looking recursively in the folder and its subfolders. If the file is found, is moved to `$destination_folder`

Comment: Worth noting that this script must be saved with a .ps1 extension and run through Powershell.